# Add Error method with escape = false doesn't work in lightning Experience why?

Tags: trigger, lightning, bug

I have added a validation in Account Trigger to prevent the deletion of Account record if the status is other than **Archived**

```
for(Account objAccount: lstOldAccount){
    if(objAccount.Status__c != 'Archived'){
      objAccount.addError('<h1 style="color:red;">You can not delete an account with live status.</h1>', false);
    }
}
```

So When I try to delete an account with active status is show the error with html formatted

[image]

But when you go back to lighting Experience and try to delete the same record with active status

It shows the HTML code and **escape=false** doesn't work it seems

[image]

is it a Salesforce bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the idea [HTML tags in the error message are escaped even if escape = false is specified at sObject.addError() in Lightning UI and Salesforce1](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000188igQAA&title=html-tags-in-the-error-message-are-escaped-even-if-escape-false-is-specified-at-sobject-adderror-on-lighting-ui)

Sounds like they aren't going to fix/change it.

> This limitation has been documented at
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_field_addError.

From the linked [`addError(errorMsg, escape)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2) docs:

> *escape*
>   Type: Boolean
>   Indicates whether any HTML markup in the custom error message should be escaped (true) or not (false). **This parameter is ignored in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce app and the HTML is always escaped. The escape parameter only applies in Salesforce Classic.**

Comment: Ahh, I missed the documentation part somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While Salesforce fixes the bug, you can use the below workaround.

I created a dummy trigger to see what request URL we get in classic and Salesforce.

```
trigger ProofTrigger on Proof__c (after insert, after update) {
    System.debug(System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());

}
```

When in classic the Debug I get

```
https://pranaydev.my.salesforce.com/a0Y0E00000217jk/e
```

whereas in Lightning the debug I get is

```
https://pranaydev.my.salesforce.com/aura?r=67&ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.saveRecord=1
```

So you can write an if-else to use the following feature to your advantage.

```
for(Account objAccount: lstOldAccount){

    if(objAccount.Status__c != 'Archived'){ // This is classic
      if(!System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm().contains('aura')){
        objAccount.addError('<h1 style="color:red;">You can not delete an account with live status.</h1>', false);
      }else{ // This is lightning
        objAccount.addError('You can not delete an account with live status.');
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man for the solution, But I was looking why it is not working.